# Install Node Red LG TV control in Home Assistant OS

Tags: node-red, raspberry-pi4, home-assistant

I'm a newbie hoping to control my LG TV with Node-Red in Home Assistant OS running on a Raspberry Pi 4.

I've tried to install ["node-red-contrib-lgtv"](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-lgtv) from within "manage pallete" of Node red but I get the following errors;

```
2022-02-12T07:16:31.961Z Install : node-red-contrib-lgtv 1.1.0

2022-02-12T07:16:34.043Z npm install --no-audit --no-update-notifier --no-fund --save --save-prefix=~ --production --engine-strict node-red-contrib-lgtv@1.1.0
2022-02-12T07:16:42.828Z [err] npm
2022-02-12T07:16:42.828Z [err]  
2022-02-12T07:16:42.828Z [err] ERR! code
2022-02-12T07:16:42.829Z [err]  126
2022-02-12T07:16:42.829Z [err] npm ERR!
2022-02-12T07:16:42.830Z [err]  path /config/node-red/node_modules/utf-8-validate
2022-02-12T07:16:42.836Z [err] npm ERR! command failed
2022-02-12T07:16:42.836Z [err] npm ERR! command
2022-02-12T07:16:42.837Z [err]  sh -c node-gyp-build
2022-02-12T07:16:42.837Z [err] npm ERR! sh: node-gyp-build: Permission denied
2022-02-12T07:16:42.884Z [err] 
2022-02-12T07:16:42.884Z [err] npm
2022-02-12T07:16:42.885Z [err]  ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-02-12T07:16:42.885Z [err] npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-12T07_16_42_840Z-debug.log
2022-02-12T07:16:42.908Z rc=126
```

I suspect it's a dependency problem but unfortunately, the link to "dependencies status" on the main page is not working.

Any idea what these errors mean and how I can install this correctly?

Comment: Have you checked the log file mentioned in the error message? `/root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-12T07_16_42_840Z-debug.log` Also I assume this is all running in a Docker container provided by Home Assistant?

Comment: I can't seem to find that log file in the terminal. Im running Home Assistant OS in a Raspberry Pi. The directories at root are "addons backup config share ssl"

Comment: It's weird because that log file doesn't seem to exist in the terminal or the file editor. I tried to cd to /root/.npm/logs and got "No such file or directory"

Comment: It will be a path inside the (home assistant supplied) Node-RED container.

Comment: The only directories in the "node-red" directory are "lib node_modules node". No root directory. I tried cd .npm but there was "no such file or directory".

Comment: This is a Docker Container, not a directory. The `node-red` directory you have access to is most likely the volume mounted into the container on `/config/node-red` and it is possible the permissions are messed up on that directory. But this is a question for the Home Assistant forum, not Stack Overflow.